# presentViewController:animated:completion: does not animate View Controller into view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, animation

I am trying to debug a really weird issue in the following code:

```
if(condition1) {
   ImageViewController* imageViewer = [[ImageViewController alloc] initWithImageData:tappedItem];
   [self presentViewController:imageViewer animated:YES completion:^{
      [imageViewer loadImage];
   }];
}
else if(condition2) {
   DocumentViewController* docViewer = [[DocumentViewController alloc] init];
   [self presentViewController:docViewer animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

In other words, depending on the state of `condition1` and `condition2`, one of two subclasses of `UIViewController` will be displayed modally to the user.

In the second case all is well, but in the first the view controller is not presented with the usual animation that shows it sliding in from the bottom of the screen. Instead, after a brief delay, it just shows up all of a sudden, covering the entire screen. Another oddity is that in the dismissal animation, the image view inside the view controller is transparent.

Removing the completion block has no effect. Replacing my view controller with an instance of `UIViewController` also has no effect, other than demonstrating that for some reason, animations don't work for `UIViewController` instances either.

Thinking that maybe I did something wrong in `viewDidLoad` etc, I tried commenting out the view load/appear methods but to no avail.

Pushing the view controller onto the nav stack is not an option because the app has a tab bar and I don't want to be visible.

**update**

Replacing my instance of `ImageViewController` with a `DocumentViewController` does result in an animation. The question now becomes: what could I have done in `ImageViewController` to mess up the animation?

Comment: coulnd't you just say: [self loadImage] in viewDidLoad of imageViewer or so?

Comment: I could and used to but there was some weirdness happening with a `UIActivityIndicatorView` in there so I moved it.

Comment: What if you present a DocumentViewController in both conditions?

Comment: @rey If I do that, the `DocumentViewController` presents with a proper animation.

Comment: Then the answer lies in the differences between the implementations of the DocumentViewController and the ImageViewController. Perhaps you can paste the relevant implementation details for the ImageViewController.

Comment: @rey Exactly. However, since the view controllers in question are radically different under the hood, I figured there were probably some general things that one needs to be careful about... anyway, I managed to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution but I still have no idea what the real cause was.

The fix was to set a background color for the view of the `UIViewController` being displayed modally in its `viewDidload` method e.g.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

If I ever figure out what really happened, I will post here.

Comment: I've just experienced the same thing. Bizarre!

Comment: Update: in my case it was because the NIB wasn't being loaded. Once I fixed that issue the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

How about presenting the view controller on the tab bar controller:

```
if(condition1) {
   ImageViewController* imageViewer = [[ImageViewController alloc] initWithImageData:tappedItem];
   [self.tabBarController presentViewController:imageViewer animated:YES completion:^{
      [imageViewer loadImage];
   }];
}
else if(condition2) {
   DocumentViewController* docViewer = [[DocumentViewController alloc] init];
   [self.tabBarController presentViewController:docViewer animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Nope, still doesn't animate.

Comment: Is there any codes that do animation at the same time as when the `ImageViewController` is presented?

Comment: No. At least not at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well.. changing the background colour didn't really help.
I did the following - it turns up to be quite nice:

```
 -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
     [super viewWillAppear:NO];
     self.view.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
     self.view.hidden = TRUE;
     self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0;
}

 -(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
     [super viewDidAppear:NO];
     float width = self.view.frame.size.width;
     float height = self.view.frame.size.height;
     self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, height, width, height);
     self.view.hidden = FALSE;
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f animations:^{
     self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 1;
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

}];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the background color works for me in iOS 8.
Also uncheck the opaque setting in the Interface Builder works!